# ZendFramework 2 - Set Different error layouts for different modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am new with Zend 2.3 and creating a web application. In this web application, I have two different modules and they have two different layout structures.

I have already set different layouts for both modules which only works when there is no any error in dispatch. 
Now I want to set different layouts for 404 error pages.

Below is both modules onBootstrap() ::

**Module A Module.php**

```
public function onBootstrap($e) {
        $eventManager   = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function($event) use ($serviceManager ) {
            $response = $event->getResponse();
            if ($response->getStatusCode() == "404")
            {
                $controller = $event->getTarget();
                $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
                $config = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config');
                $controller->layout('modulea/error');
            }
        }, -100);

        $eventManager->getSharedManager()
            ->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
                $controller = $e->getTarget();
                $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
                $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));
                $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config');
                if (isset($config['module_layouts'][$moduleNamespace])) {
                    $controller->layout($config['module_layouts'][$moduleNamespace]);
                }
            }, 100);
    }
```

**Module A module.config.php**

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'modulea/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/modulea.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'modulea/error'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
            'javascripts'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/javascripts.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
           'modulea' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    'module_layouts' => array(
        'Modulea' => 'layout/modulea.phtml'
    ),
```

Same way for another module Module B. But its not working. For each module it takes Application layout for error page.

Please kindly help me in this problem.

Comment: What is the namespace? Check the case of the string as `ModuleA` namespace will not match `Modulea` in `isset($config['module_layouts'][$moduleNamespace])` nor will `$controller->layout('ModuleA/error')` match the layout template `modulea/error`.

Comment: @AlexP Sorry, I have just changed modules names in question. But in my code it is same in both module.config.php and Module.php on bootstrap function. I am getting :: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Mvc\Application::layout()